# slideUp Individual Element

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using a jQuery/Ajax script that submits a form without reloading the page. I have multiple forms on the page and they all have the same class (and no id). This works fine to submit the form using:

```
    $('document').ready(function()
{
    $('.form').ajaxForm( {
        success: function() {
            //$('.form').addClass("clicked");
            //$(this).slideUp('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

but as soon as I want to do something when the submission is successful there doesn't appear to be a way to refer to the form that is submitted. Using the this operator would make sense but it doesn't work. I want to do something like this:

```
$(this).slideUp('fast');
```

for each element individually depending on which form was submitted. (Using .form as the selector doesn't work as it hides all of the forms).

I've tried adding a class to the form (though can't seem to refer to the right element either) to then use to call the slideUp function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajaxForm plugin you're using provides a reference to the form in the success callback:

```
success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    $form.slideUp("fast");
}
```

Documentation: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

If you weren't using this plugin, you'd have to maintain that reference yourself. One popular approach is to preserve the reference to the appropriate `this` by assigning it to something like `self`:

```
$(".form").on("submit", function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        success: function () {
            $(self).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) Worked perfectly. Should have thought to look into the plugin itself

Answer (score 1):

The plugin gives you another method - `ajaxSubmit()` - which can be used as follows :

```
$('.form').submit(function() { 
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.ajaxSubmit({
        success: function() {
            $form.addClass("clicked").slideUp('fast');//or whatever
        }
    });     
    return false; //suppress natural form submission
});
```